# SQL Server bind named instances to specific IP addresses

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to bind a named instance of SQL server to a sepcific IP address so that it is accessible just by IP address without the instance name?

For example, suppose I have two IP addresses 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2, and two named instances SQL1 and SQL2, all on a single server.  I want to bind the IP addresses to the instances respectively so that connections to 192.168.1.1 go to sql1 and 192.168.1.2 go to sql2, rather than having to connect to 192.168.1.1\sql1 and 192.168.1.2\sql2.

What I am after is this.  I have two separate servers, sql1 and sql2 that are on out of date hardware.  I want to migrate both servers' IP address and databases into separate instances on a new server without having to update any applications that connect to them.

Any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you use a hostfile to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If they are named instances then keep the same instance names but set up DNS CNAME aliases

So `oldserver1\sql1` and `oldserver2\sql2` still work because the host names `oldserverX` both resolve to `newserver` thanks to the magic of DNS.

If the instance names are the same, then you'd have to use client aliases I reckon. Binding SQL Server to a given IP address would be a nightmare because no instance name implies port 1433 for both. Or 2x virtual boxes...